# Clean way to give MVC urls to javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript library that I have written that I want to be able to use similar to how bootstrap's libraries are use. That is, I want to drive them from data attributes on elements in the page.

The problem is this library needs to know of a url to a specific part of our site (server api that performs a utility function). There are multiple instance of our website deployed with a variety of different configurations, so absolute urls, relative and `~/` all don't work for this situation.

The only ways I can think of currently to provide this link is to either put it as a data attribute on the element that is using the js, or in a script tag. The former is messy and the latter is annoying as I would like the library to just work if you reference the script/bundle.

My question is, is there an alternative way to provide js a mvc-generated url that is cleaner and preferably more centralised than the alternatives mentioned above?

Comment: Not clear what your asking - you start by saying _I want to drive them from data attributes on elements in the page._ but then later say that doing that  _is messy_

Comment: @StephenMuecke I consider having to provide a url in every usageto be messy as the library only needs it once and the element doesnt care about what the library needs internally

Comment: Your js library could always have a (say) `Initialize(url)` function that you call from the main view (passing it the url) which sets a variable in the library.

Comment: Do you have opportunity to pass a prefix url to your library during initialization? I don't understand why you have to hardcode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try this

1. Load your js lib
2. call a default endpoint (could be a web api) during initialization stage of your js library. Or When you project is build create json file which contains all the urls, and load this json file from script. I think it depends on if you need dynamically generate these urls.
3. your web api return you a json object which contains all the url you need.

then

1. you do not need to messy up your data annotation
2. you do not need to use script tag.
3. you have a centralized storage of all your urls.

Comment: The problem is that endpoint url varies depending on where the site is deployed. Eg: on one site the base url would be `www.mysite.com`, another it would be `www.corp.com/mysite`. asp.net knows the difference so `@Url.Content("~/foo")` works, but hardcoding somthing in a static file wont.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this, except instead loading an object into the dom that contains utility urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the base url of a site with:

```
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/"
```